# Sage One API - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0, guzzle, sage-one

I am trying to obtain an access token for Sage One API by following the [docs](https://developers.sageone.com/docs/en/v1#authentication-request_access_token) using [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)(v6) / Laravel 5.2 (Laravel's involvement is irrelevant for this question), it is stuck at the "request access token" stage.

**The error**

```
Client error: `POST https://api.sageone.com/oauth2/token` resulted in a
 `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

**The offending code**

```
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri'=>'https://api.sageone.com',
        'headers' => ['content_type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']
    ]);
    $data = [
        'client_id' => getenv('SAGE_CLIENT'),
        'client_secret' => getenv('SAGE_SECRET'),
        'code' => $request->code,
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'redirect_uri'=>'https://myurl.com/sage/refresh'
    ];

    $response = $client->request('POST','/oauth2/token',['json' => $data]);
```

The docs state ***"grant_type - The type of grant the code relates to. Either authorization_code or refresh_token."***, I have tried both. The other vars are all fine and dandy, just the `grant_type` appears to fail.

**UPDATE 1**
The debug header generates the output below.

```
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped * Trying 52.49.116.133... 
* Connected to api.sageone.com (52.49.116.133) port 443 (#0) 
* CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none 
* ALPN/NPN, server did not agree to a protocol 
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 
* Server certificate: 
* subject: CN=api.sageone.com,O=The Sage Group PLC,L=Newcastle Upon Tyne,ST=Newcastle Upon Tyne,C=GB,serialNumber=02231246,businessCategory=Private Organization,incorporationCountry=GB 
* start date: May 12 00:00:00 2014 GMT 
* expire date: May 11 23:59:59 2016 GMT 
* common name: api.sageone.com 
* issuer: CN=GeoTrust Extended Validation SSL CA - G2,O=GeoTrust Inc.,C=US > POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1 Host: api.sageone.com content_type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.1.1 curl/7.43.0 PHP/5.6.18 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Content-Length: 216 
* upload completely sent off: 216 out of 216 bytes < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request < Content-Type: application/json < Date: Tue, 08 Mar 2016 10:53:09 GMT < Server: openresty < Content-Length: 26 < Connection: keep-alive < 
* Connection #0 to host api.sageone.com left intact
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are POST-ing the values as JSON encoded data but you should POST with form-encoded. See: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params, so

```
$response = $client->request('POST','/oauth2/token',['form_params' => $data]);
```

**EDIT:**

You should check your code again since I've just verified and double-checked that this change makes it work on the live sage environment. The complete code that I used:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri'=>'https://api.sageone.com',
        'headers' => ['content_type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']
    ]);

$data = [
    'client_id' => getenv('SAGE_CLIENT'),
    'client_secret' => getenv('SAGE_SECRET'),
    'code' => getenv('SAGE_CODE'),
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri'=>'https://myurl.com/sage/refresh'
];

$response = $client->request('POST','/oauth2/token',['form_params' => $data]);

echo $response->getBody();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @HansZ, but that did nothing at all. Still "unsupported_grant_type"

Comment: can you add `'debug' => true` and see what gets sent on the wire, see http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/request-options.html#debug

Comment: technically the debug request option should provide you with the full Request and Response from the server.  Is it safe to presume that your code snippet is a simplification of your actual code? If so then the request that is being sent (as shown) should occur after your authorization request.  When you view your request, is the "code" that is sent within the request for access token an expected value?

Comment: @ShaunBramley - No, that is all the relevant code. Aside from the Guzzle Client dependency, there is nothing further. Do you want to see the whole controller class?

Comment: @DanWhite - The whole controller; as much as possible.  The whole debug output that contains the request / response as sent across the wire, would be useful as well.

Comment: explicitly setting-up the content-type made it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using json for oAuth is indeed incorrect: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3
I think, this is incorrect:

```
$response = $client->request('POST','/oauth2/token',['json' => json_encode($data)]);
```

Instead, I would try something like this:

```
$response = $client->post('/oauth2/token', [], $data);
```

OR this

```
$response = $client->post('/oauth2/token', ['body' => $data]);
```

Another question, what about the first call `https://www.sageone.com/oauth2/auth` - did it go through?

Comment: Body worked, thanks @Axalix. Curious to know why this did and not form_params though.

Comment: body doesn't work ('InvalidArgumentException') in recent versions of Guzzle and is deprecated; use `form_params`